# Power Automate not showing all columns from SQL

Tags: power-automate

I have created a Power Automate flow which is running fine. It connects to SQL Server using on-premise data gateway, gets the records from a table using GetRows action and put the response on a file hosted on SharePoint.  But there is one problem. It seems a date field is missing from response, even it exists in the table. Have any idea how to fix this?